# Is sinus an unique function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

On $\mathbb{R}$, is sinus (the sine function) the unique $C^{\infty}$ function $f$ with all its derivatives and itself  between $-1$ and $1$ and also $ \frac{df}{dx}(0)=1 $ ?

Comment: No.  Just integrate any smooth function with its image in $[-1,1]$ which has value $1$ at $0$.

Comment: I suspect you've made a typo. I've never heard of the sinus function.

Comment: @MattSamuel At least in Euler's time (if not later), sin and cos were known as sinus and cosinus. It does sound a bit odd to the modern ear.

Comment: @user_of_math That's very interesting, I didn't know that. Perhaps the OP speaks a language where the name survived then.

Comment: @MattSamuel A professor of mine from France uses sinus and cosinus still for sin/cos

Comment: Sinus and cosinus are the names of the functions in danish (and at lot of other languages I guess).

Comment: Check Wikipedia, it seems majority of available languages uses a version of _sinus_ rather than shorter sine, seno, sen, etc.

Comment: @Gaffney: $g(x)=1$ is a smooth function with it's image in $[-1,1]$ and value $1$ at $0$, but if you integrate it you get $x$, which is not between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @Henrik  I didn't see the "and itself" part.  Good call.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm french, and in France they say sinus and cosinus for sin and cos :)

Comment: @Shadock guess that confirms everyone's suspicion!

Comment: Complete tangent, but I thought it was interesting: _Sine_ comes from Latin _sinus_ 'fold in a garment, curve', because a mid-12th century author translating a text misread Arabic _jiba_ 'chord, sine' as _jaib_ 'fold in a garment'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly tangential to your question (so I am CWing it), but the sine function can be uniquely characterized by a differential equation, much like $\cos$, $\tan$, $\exp$, &c.

> *Claim* Suppose $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is such that $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f''+f=0$. Then $f=0$

*Proof* From $f''=f$ we get $f''f'=ff'$ and integrating and using the initial conditions gives $(f')^2+f^2=0$. This gives $f'=0$ and hence $f=0$.

> *Claim* Suppose $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is such that $f(0)=a, f'(0)=b$ and $f''+f=0$. Then $f=a\cos +b\sin$.

*Proof* Let $g=f-a\cos -b\sin $. Then $g(0)=f(0)-a=0=g'(0)=f'(0)-b=0$, and $g''+g=0$. Hence $g=0$ by the above, i.e. $f=a\cos +b\sin$. In particular, $\sin$ ($\cos$) is uniquely characterized by $f(0)=0,f'(0)=1$ ($f(0)=1,f'(0)=0$) and $f''+f=0$